# function to set boolean day of week variables

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have 7 boolean variables: mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun

The function I need to create accepts 2 integer variables:

```
SetDays(int from, int to) 
// "from" can be greater or smaller than "to" for example
//SetDays(7,3) must set sun,mon,tue,wed to true;
//SetDays(1,4) must set mon,tue,wed,thur to true;
```

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out an algorithm for this SetDays function. Could someone help me?

Comment: Show the code you've written so far.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do here, you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: First: you probably want an vector (or array) of Booleans, not seven separate variables. Second, look up the remainder operator (`%`).

Answer (score 1):

The comments you're receiving are valid - an array would be a better bet, possibly in combination with an `enum`, then you could use `%` to iterate while wrapping from the end to the start.

Anyway, for the question as asked, just work through the logic for each.  There's basically two situations - when `from < to`, and when it's not....

```
void SetDays(int from, int to)
{
    sun = from < to ? to == 7 : true;
    mon = from < to ? from == 1 : true;
    ...etc...
}
```